# Display original (conditional) brushed unbrushed crossfilter bars with dc.js with different colors

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Say we have the following crossfilter / dc.js app:

[image: Original]

While this is nice, the user loses "reference" the population when brushing. I would like for charts `x`, `y`, `z`, and `a` to keep the "underlying" bars when other charts are brushed. Perhaps in a different color like so:

[image: Desired Results]

I believe this may require updating the `dc.renderAll()` function, but I am not sure even how to start.

---

Here is all the code to reproduce this app with the .csv data hosted as a gist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Data Exploration Tool MVP</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unpkg.com/dc@3/dc.css"/>
    <style>
      #data-count {
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        float: none;
      }
      table {
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      td {
        width: 1%;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 10px;">

  <div class="row">
    <h2>Data Exploration Tool</h2>
    <div class="col-md-3 well well-sm">
      <div class="dc-data-count" id="data-count">
          <span class="filter-count"></span>
           selected out of
          <span class="total-count"></span>
           points |
          <a href="javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <!-- First row of charts -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-11" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-11-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">range: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_11.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-12" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-12-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_12.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-13" style="width:100%;">
              <div id="chart-13-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_13.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="chart-14" style="width:100%;">
                <div id="chart-14-title"></div>
              <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
                <a href="javascript:chart_14.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Second row of chart -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-21" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-21-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_21.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-22" style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-22-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">range: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_22.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="chart-23"style="width:100%;">
            <div id="chart-23-title"></div>
            <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
              <a href="javascript:chart_23.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="chart-24"style="width:100%;">
              <div id="chart-24-title"></div>
              <div class="reset" style="visibility: hidden;">selected: <span class="filter"></span>
                <a href="javascript:chart_24.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();">reset</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.1/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="http://unpkg.com/dc@3/dc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

'use strict';

dc.config.defaultColors(d3.schemeSet1);

var 
    chart_11   = dc.barChart("#chart-11"),
    chart_12   = dc.barChart("#chart-12"),
    chart_13   = dc.barChart("#chart-13"),
    chart_21   = dc.barChart("#chart-21"),
    chart_22   = dc.barChart("#chart-22"),
    chart_23   = dc.barChart("#chart-23"),
    data_count = dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count");

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JasonAizkalns/32ece5c815f9ac5d540c41dc0825bbab/raw/362050300ddcb99f195044c00d9f26b0d7d489ca/data.csv").then(function(data) {

var var_names = ["x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c"];

$("#chart-11-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[0], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-12-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[1], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-13-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[2], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-21-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[3], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-22-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[4], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));
$("#chart-23-title").append(["<h5>", var_names[5], "<br>Subtitle</h5>"].join(""));

var c11_bin = 10,
    c12_bin = 10,
    c13_bin = 500,
    c21_bin = 100,
    c22_bin = 20,
    c23_bin = 1000;


var ndx = crossfilter(data),

    chart_11_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[0]]; }),
    chart_12_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[1]]; }),
    chart_13_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[2]]; }),
    chart_21_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[3]]; }),
    chart_22_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[4]]; }),
    chart_23_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d[var_names[5]]; }),

    chart_11_grp = chart_11_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c11_bin) * c11_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_12_grp = chart_12_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c12_bin) * c12_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_13_grp = chart_13_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c13_bin) * c13_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_21_grp = chart_21_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c21_bin) * c21_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_22_grp = chart_22_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c22_bin) * c22_bin }).reduceCount(),
    chart_23_grp = chart_23_dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / c23_bin) * c23_bin }).reduceCount();

var all = ndx.groupAll();

data_count.dimension(ndx)
  .group(all);

var chart_11_min = +chart_11_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[0]],
    chart_11_max = +chart_11_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[0]],
    chart_12_min = +chart_12_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[1]],
    chart_12_max = +chart_12_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[1]],
    chart_13_min = +chart_13_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[2]],
    chart_13_max = +chart_13_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[2]],
    chart_21_min = +chart_21_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[3]],
    chart_21_max = +chart_21_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[3]],
    chart_22_min = +chart_22_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[4]],
    chart_22_max = +chart_22_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[4]],
    chart_23_min = +chart_23_dim.bottom(1)[0][var_names[5]],
    chart_23_max = +chart_23_dim.top(1)[0][var_names[5]];

var breathing_room = 0.05;

chart_11
  .dimension(chart_11_dim)
  .group(chart_11_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_11_min - ((chart_11_max - chart_11_min) * breathing_room), chart_11_max + ((chart_11_max - chart_11_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c11_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_12
  .dimension(chart_12_dim)
  .group(chart_12_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_12_min - ((chart_12_max - chart_12_min) * breathing_room), chart_12_max + ((chart_12_max - chart_12_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c12_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_13
  .dimension(chart_13_dim)
  .group(chart_13_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_13_min - ((chart_13_max - chart_13_min) * breathing_room), chart_13_max + ((chart_13_max - chart_13_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c13_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_21
  .dimension(chart_21_dim)
  .group(chart_21_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_21_min - ((chart_21_max - chart_21_min) * breathing_room), chart_21_max + ((chart_21_max - chart_21_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c21_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_22
  .dimension(chart_22_dim)
  .group(chart_22_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_22_min - ((chart_22_max - chart_22_min) * breathing_room), chart_22_max + ((chart_22_max - chart_22_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c22_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

chart_23
  .dimension(chart_23_dim)
  .group(chart_23_grp)
  .round(dc.round.floor)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([chart_23_min - ((chart_23_max - chart_23_min) * breathing_room), chart_23_max + ((chart_23_max - chart_23_min) * breathing_room)]))
  .xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / c23_bin; })
  .controlsUseVisibility(true);

dc.renderAll();

});

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yeah, neither dc.js nor crossfilter directly supports this use case, not that people don't want it.

Crossfilter only supports one active filter and gives you no way to find out what the totals were when no filters were applied.

**EDIT**: *there is now an [official example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/compare-unfiltered.html) with code cleaned up in response to [the follow up code review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215041/48977). The below discussion still describes the technique well, but the code is less repetitive in the example.*

Thanks for the reproducible example to start with. I [put your original code in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/sbg5cjxw/3/).

It's a little tedious, but one way to get the affect you are after is to change each chart into a [composite](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.compositeChart.html) of two bar charts. We'll make the second subchart red and hide it until something is filtered. (More precisely, we'll hide it whenever there is nothing filtered.)

And we'll make the first (blue) subchart always show the initial values, not affected by any filters.

Creating a composite chart looks like this:

```
var chart_11   = dc.compositeChart("#chart-11"),
    chart_12   = dc.compositeChart("#chart-12"),
    chart_13   = dc.compositeChart("#chart-13"),
    chart_21   = dc.compositeChart("#chart-21"),
    chart_22   = dc.compositeChart("#chart-22"),
    chart_23   = dc.compositeChart("#chart-23");
chart_11
    .compose([
        dc.barChart(chart_11)
            .dimension(chart_11_dim)
            .group(chart_11_grp_copy)
            .controlsUseVisibility(true)
        ,
        dc.barChart(chart_11)
            .dimension(chart_11_dim)
            .group(chart_11_grp)
            .colors('red')
            .controlsUseVisibility(true)
            .brushOn(false)
    ]);
```

(Yes it seems you have to apply `controlsUseVisibility` to every child chart - looks like a bug.)

The heart of the problem is how to make the underlying blue chart not change. We can use a 
[fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) for this. The idea is this object acts like a group except it just returns what the group had on page load:

```
function static_copy_group(group) {
    var all = group.all().map(kv => ({key: kv.key, value: kv.value}));
    return {
            all: function() {
            return all;
        }
    }
}
var chart_11_grp_copy = static_copy_group(chart_11_grp),
    chart_12_grp_copy = static_copy_group(chart_12_grp),
    chart_13_grp_copy = static_copy_group(chart_13_grp),
    chart_21_grp_copy = static_copy_group(chart_21_grp),
    chart_22_grp_copy = static_copy_group(chart_22_grp),
    chart_23_grp_copy = static_copy_group(chart_23_grp);
```

Yes, that's a deep copy of `group.all()` because crossfilter updates everything in place.

Finally, here's the code to hide the second chart when nothing is filtered:

```
function any_filters() {
    return [chart_11, chart_12, chart_13, chart_21, chart_22, chart_23]
        .some(chart => chart.filters().length);
}

function hide_second_chart(chart) {
    chart.select('.sub._1')
        .attr('visibility', any_filters() ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
}

[chart_11, chart_12, chart_13, chart_21, chart_22, chart_23].forEach(function(chart) {
   chart.on('pretransition', hide_second_chart)
})
```

[image: charts with context/reference underlay]

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/sbg5cjxw/43/).

Comment: Thank you -- I am assuming when you say Crossfilter does not support this that your comment extends to Reductio and Universe? FYI: I also have this posted on [`Code Review`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215041/48977) for function / code clean-up -- feels like a nice example that others (especially those less comfortable with JS) could leverage -- crosstalking between visualizations is still a sore spot in other languages, especially analysis-centric languages such as R.

Comment: Not sure why, but I'm receiving `(index):213 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: chart_11.compose is not a function` when trying to run locally. I have `d3` loaded via: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Whoops, I missed another change - yes you need `compositeChart`s not `barChart`s - the composite chart overlays a bunch of ordinary charts on top of each other.

Comment: Would you be cool with making this into an example for the [dc.js examples page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/)? And right, I don't know of anything in reductio or universe that will help with this. (I originally got involved with dc.js in order to [bring these charts to R via RCloud](https://github.com/att/rcloud.dcplot). Sadly, no htmlwidget version yet, and no integration with crosstalk... stuff I'd love to do if I find time.)

Comment: of course, this has always been on the backburner for me -- something that crosstalk doesn't do well nor is [plotly ready to scale](https://resources.rstudio.com/webinars/accessing-and-responding-to-plotly-events-in-shiny-carson-sievert) quite as fast yet. I think it should be cleaned up before an example page, (maybe wait a few days for someone to chime in on Code Review) but let me know.

Comment: That's a good point, it would need some cleanup. I guess I am reluctant to go down the rabbit hole of how to create a system of N charts, although I have implemented them a couple of times. It's not too hard to clean up the code as it is, but if you try to support multiple charts or the many ways that a bar chart can be set up, it kind of explodes. (The "general purpose chart builder" is the Holy Grail in this space.) So I'm sorry, but I think I will pass on the code review this time.

Comment: I'll see if anyone makes some nice contributions; I'm also going to maybe toss this example to some R users making strides in crosstalk / plotly space which tend to generalize / extend better, but take a hit on performance. Still might be worth a small clean-up or posting -- this is definitely a use-case / template I'm keeping in my back pocket as it comes up frequently.