# Original Data Display on chart after filtering (DC.js)

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to display original data on my DC.js chart [(similar to this)](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/compare-unfiltered.html) once filtered by using a "[fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups)".

I followed the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070101/12728698) post, and haven't had luck. I'm wondering if it's because I'm using `reductio`?

Also, maybe it's because I'm using key/value accessor functions??:

```
.keyAccessor((d) => {
    return d.key;
})
.valueAccessor((d) => {
    return d.value.avg;
}),
```

Here's the [stackblitz minimal implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-j3115w?file=components%2Fdc%2FTransitTimeScatter.tsx), interested to hear any insight!

Comment: Does it make sense to compare the unfiltered data using any chart except for the bar chart? I have never seen it and I can’t imagine how it would work. The bar chart has the nice property that the filtered bars automatically denote a portion of unfiltered bars on which they are overlaid. *Maybe* an area chart, but I’ve never seen it. A scatter plot? Nah.

Comment: @Gordon I think you can just imagine the charts I’m plotting as bar charts, except they’re scatter points instead of bars (aesthetic choice). Just to be clear, are you saying it’s not possible for some reason, or just doesn’t make sense?

Comment: @Gordon, P.S. I converted one of the series into a bar chart (both originally), and you can see that the staticCopy is still being filtered, any idea why?

Comment: Got it. In general a scatter plot wouldn't be interpretable because you wouldn't be able to tell which dot is which. But you have just one Y per X, so it makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in fact a reductio "problem" as it creates a more complicated group object

e.g.

```
key: foo
value: {
  avg: bar,
  sum: baz,
  etc.
}
```

so the "deep copy" from the linked post

```
  function static_copy_group(group) {
      var all = group.all().map(kv => ({key: kv.key, value: kv.value}));
      return {
          all: function() {
              return all;
          }
      }
  }
```

is in fact still referencing. Fixed by using the [clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone) library instead

Comment: Nice. In this case, changing to `{...kv.value}` would do it, but clone should work in every case.